# Setting limits in django (preventing too many hits on a view)

Tags: python, django, security

Not sure of the customs for people who release production django apps but I'd assume there is some kind of protection mechanism against people who spam a view or so?

If a view did not implement caching and a user just spams the url a bunch of times wouldn't that be a bad thing?

I want some mechanism to block people by IP address or whatnot if they are repeatedly calling a view at a high rate.

I tried to use this app: http://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

But it promptly does not work, or perhaps my setup is wrong (has anyone used it?).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you look into Django Rest framework's throttling? http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this kind of security would happen at the web server level, i.e. in Nginx or whatever you're using to serve your app. Think about the fact that in order to block someone's IP in your app after a certain number of attempts you'd need to record their IP somewhere and then check incoming requests against that. If it were to go in your app then this kind of functionality would best fit at a middleware level.

If you were to do this at an application level for the purpose of protecting individual views then I would probably do it by means of a decorator.

You should have a mechanism in place for this anyway, as what you've described can also be a Denial of Service attack in the right context. Some web hosts have hardware-level protection for this, so ask your host about that too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in production you have some kind of frontend server. If your application logic not coupled to the number of requests, better do this work on frontend. For example Nginx has limit_req module:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html